# Setting overflow: hidden on <body> results in 1px white padding on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, background-image

I have a background image for a webpage that is too big, and in general, I want to prevent scrolling on the webpage.  The HTML looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            Test
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS looks like

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    background-image: url("bg.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    display: table;
}
```

This code mostly achieves the desired effect (background image looks good and scrolling is prevented); however, in iOS Safari, the `overflow: hidden;` (which prevents scrollbars/scrolling) seems to introduce ~1px of white space around the right and bottom of the display area.  I can get rid of the margin by doing something like `padding: 1px` instead of `padding: 0`, but then the scrollbars come back.  Any ideas on how to get rid of this small whitespace while still preventing scrolling?

I tried adding a wrapper `<div>` for all the `<body>` content and setting the background and overflow properties on the `<div>`, but still didn't have luck (either got scrollbars or the odd small margins on bottom and right).

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet and test that it shows the problem on IOS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not entirely clear why you get that white band(s) a slightly hacky workaround would be to put the background onto a before pseudo element which you make just slightly larger than the body.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 1px);
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/1024);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

body {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    Test
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are a wizard! :) Using the pseudoelement before the body works perfectly.  The only addition I had to make was to add `z-index: -1` on `body::before` so that the pseudoelement didn't cover all the content.  Thank you!